# How can I make this function taking an array of arrays as input compile with numba?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numba

The signature of the function is

```
def SLBQP(Q, q, u, a, x, eps=1e-6, maxIter=1000):
```

and it returns a float64.

The types of the arguments are:

```
Q -- np.array([[1., 2.], [4., 5.]])
q -- np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])
u -- a scalar
a -- np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])
x -- np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])
```

I tried

```
@jit('f8(f8[:,:], f8[:], f8, f8[:], f8[:], f8, i4)',nopython=True)
def SLBQP(Q, q, u, a, x, eps=1e-6, maxIter=1000):
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function array>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 1d, C))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    TypingError: array(float64, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence
    raised from /Users/gerardozinno/Desktop/ProgettoML/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/typing/npydecl.py:472
In definition 1:
    TypingError: array(float64, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence
    raised from /Users/gerardozinno/Desktop/ProgettoML/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/typing/npydecl.py:472
```

I've also tried this:

```
@jit('numba.float64(numba.array(float64, 2d, C), numba.array(float64, 1d, C), numba.float64, numba.array(float64, 1d, C), numba.array(float64, 1d, C), numba.float64, numba.int64)',nopython=True)
```

and it gives me a syntax error.

EDIT:

I tried with this signature :

```
@nb.njit('f8(f8[:,:], f8[:], f8, f8[:], f8[:], f8, i4)')
```

suggested by Thane Brooker in the answer section and it gives me this error:

```
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function array>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 1d, C))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    TypingError: array(float64, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence
    raised from /Users/gerardozinno/Desktop/ProgettoML/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/typing/npydecl.py:472
In definition 1:
    TypingError: array(float64, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence
    raised from /Users/gerardozinno/Desktop/ProgettoML/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/typing/npydecl.py:472
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function array>)
[2] During: typing of call at /Users/gerardozinno/Desktop/NUOVO/ProgettoML/svr/SLBQP.py (119)


File "SLBQP.py", line 119:
def SLBQP(Q, q, u, a, x, eps=1e-6, maxIter=1000):
    <source elided>
        v = np.dot(Qx,x) + np.dot(q, x)
        g = np.array(Qx+q)
        ^
```

Comment: In g=np.array(Qx+q) what is Qx?

Comment: @Thane Brooker `Qx = np.dot(Q, x)`

Comment: [here](https://github.com/gerzin/ProgettoML/blob/master/svr/SLBQP.py) there is the file with the whole function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing this code before my function.

```
from numba.extending import overload

@overload(np.array)
def np_array_ol(x):
    if isinstance(x, types.Array):
        def impl(x):
            return np.copy(x)
    return impl

@nb.njit('f8(f8[:,:], f8[:], f8, f8[:], f8[:], f8, i4)')
def SLBQP(Q, q, u, a, x, eps=1e-6, maxIter=1000):
    ...
```

[Apparently](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4470) the error written in the edit section is caused by a bug inside numba.

Answer (score 0):

This works without error.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit('f8(f8[:,:], f8[:], f8, f8[:], f8[:], f8, i4)')
def SLBQP(Q, q, u, a, x, eps=1e-6, maxIter=1000):
    return 1.

Q = np.array([[1., 2.], [4., 5.]])
q = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])
u = 50
a = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])
x = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])

result = SLBQP(Q, q, u, a, x, eps=1e-6, maxIter=1000)
```

I changed your example Q variable (which I assume to be a typo), but otherwise I can't replicate your syntax error.  I am guessing the Q you are passing to your function is a 1D array and not the 2D array as you think it is.  Take a look at `Q.shape` and `Q.flags` to check.

Comment: It was a typo. I called numba.typeof(Q) and it returned `array(float64, 2d, C)`